# Azure Iot Hub SDK for C: which client module to use?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

we're making an IoT product with Azure IoT Hub as a backend solution. The main application is written on C and we're going to use the Azure SDK for C. We've studied the SDK and decided that we're going to use a low-level client. But here's the thing - there are multiple modules in Azure SDK that seem to be independent - `iothub_client_ll.h`, `iothub_device_client_ll.h` and `iothub_client_core_ll.h`. Which one to use?

Also we've noted that `iothub_device_client_ll.h` doesn't have the ability to process device method asynchronously and we really need that thing. But device_client module seems to be the latest one - maybe Microsoft guys are planning to remove `iothub_client_ll` modules from the SDK at all?

We couldn't find the answers to those questions on the Azure website or in the github repo docs and discussions. Anyone can help us to understand that stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this question from the field and responded via email.  For documentation purpose, I will post the response here as well.

These are really good questions.

iothub_client_ll, iothub_device_client_ll and iothub_client_core_ll

The customer should use the iothub_device_client_ll * API’s.  This is indeed the new way that we want people using going forward.  The iothub_client_core_ll is internal only (it supports device_client/legacy client/module_client).  The iothub_client_ll is what we had previously, as Sub Zero correctly surmised.

The API that seems to do asynchronous methods is not something we took into the iothub_device_client_ll.  From a service side perspective, methods are synchronous (in particular see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods, and the paragraph beginning “Direct methods are synchronous and either succeed or fail after the timeout period (default: 30 seconds, settable up to 3600 seconds”).

We understand that there are scenarios – such as a firmware update – where a method may kick off a long-running task.  We have a sample of this available here, in particular they should examine the function device_method_callback which processes the callback and then spins a thread when method_name==”FirmwareUpdate” and quickly returns.  The do_firmware_update() thread, when complete, will update its status to the server by invoking sendChillerReportedProperties() which basically updates the reported values on a twin.

The “async” method in the legacy iothub_client_ll does not integrate into the twin and had limited value, which is why we didn’t want to take it into the iothub_device_client_ll.

Answer (score 0):

If you review the source files you will see that they all call into iothub_client_core_ll so it pretty much doesn't matter which one you use. These different versions exist for backwards compatibility only.

I don't understand what you mean about processing asynchronously. The ll in these files stands for low level which means they have less dependencies than those versions without the ll. One of those is that it does not use any threading internally so that the code can be run on processors that do not support threading hence everything will run on a single thread and you will be required to call `IoTHubClient_LL_DoWork` on a regular basis (think 100 times a second) in order to connect to the hub and send and receive messages. If you need to process the device method an a second thread then you should be using the version **without** the ll designation.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the implementation, and I've seen that they all point to the same module. The question was is it safe to use iothub_explorer_ll or it's about to be removed?
About "async" device methods -- I meant [IoTHubClient_LL_SetDeviceMethodCallback_Ex](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_ll.h#L341) method that allows you to send the response to the direct method later.
And yes, I know about `DoWork` function, that was the reason we chose  the low-level libraries.

Comment: Any updates to the SDK will not include breaking changes in backward compatibility except in the instance of a major version number update. Strictly the callback methods such as the one you mentioned are not asynchronous. When dowork is called it will read any data from the socket. If this is data that requires a callback such as a direct method invocation then it will be called at that point. This will be running on the thread on which dowork was called.